# Problema con activación de usuario

Tags: php, xampp, mariadb, apache2

Actualizo, creo saber donde esta el fallo, lo marqué en el código con el numero  * 167 y espaciado/salto de línea del otro código. Checkeenló.

Por favor, léanme. No soy alumno o estudiante buscando fáciles soluciones soy un tipo más. No se programar.
Estoy intentando solucionar por qué no pasa el usuario a *activado* mediante generación de un código que se envía por email y al clickar pasa a 'activado'.
Ya he conseguido enviarme un email para probar y llega pero sigue sin activarse el usuario. Os pongo todo el código de registro y activación separado por ********

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/sbrweb.php');

//Configuración para registrar usuario y envio email con PHPMailer.
$hostname_db = "localhost";
$database_db = "cuerodb";
$username_db = "root";
$password_db = "";

$link = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db); 
$link-> set_charset("utf8");
mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);

//MONTANDO SENTENCIAS PREPARADAS
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$fecAlta = date('j-n-Y'). " " .date('g:i:s A');

// Comprobar conexión
if($link->connect_error){
die("La conexión ha fallado, error número " . $link->connect_errno . ": " . $link->connect_error);
}
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM usuarios_sbr WHERE email = ?')) {
if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
die ('Email no valido');
}
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $_POST['username']) == 0) {
die ('Username no valido!');
}
if (strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['password']) < 5) {
die ('Contraseña entre 5 y 20 caracteres');
}

// Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), hash the password using the PHP password_hash function.
$stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
// Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {

// Username already exists
echo 'El usuario existe, elija otro <a href="Registro.html">Regresar</a>';
} else {

// Username doesnt exists, insert new account
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios_sbr (nombre, username, password, email, fecAlta, activation_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) {

// We do not want to expose passwords in our database, so hash the password and use password_verify when a user logs in.
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$uniqid = uniqid();
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email'], $fecAlta, $uniqid);
$stmt->execute();

//Enviamos el email con el link de activación de la cuenta  
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer;
try {

//Server settings
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';                                // Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                             // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->Port = 587;                                          // TCP port to connect to
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'prueba@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'passprueba';                           // SMTP password

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('prueba@gmail.com', 'prueba');
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'],'prueba');            // Add a recipient

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'e-mail para activar su cuenta';

*167---> $activate_link = 'http://localhost/prueba/Usuarios/Activate.php?=' . $_POST['email'] . '&code=' . $uniqid;

$mail->Body    = '<p>Gracias por registrarse en prueba. Cuando de click al enlace se activará su cuenta: <b><a href="' . $activate_link . '">' . $activate_link . '</a></b></p>';
$mail->send();
echo '<span class="title clearfix">Se ha registrado correctamente, hemos mandado un e-mail al correo con el que se registró, ábralo y active su cuenta.</span>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo '<span class="user_box">No hemos podido mandar el e-mail. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}</span>';
}
}
}

} else {

// Something is wrong with the sql statement, check to make sure accounts table exists with all 3 fields.
echo 'Error en prepare';
}
$link->close();

//******************************************************************************************************************************************

//Configuración activar usuario.
$hostname_db = "localhost";
$database_db = "cuerodb";
$username_db = "root";
$password_db = "";

$link = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db); 
$link-> set_charset("utf8");
mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db); 

// Comprobamos si el email y el código existen...
if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['code'])) {  
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios_sbr WHERE email = ? AND activation_code = ?')) { 
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_GET['email'], $_GET['code']);
$stmt->execute();

// Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { 

// Account exists with the requested email and code.
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE usuarios_sbr SET activation_code = ? WHERE email = ? AND activation_code = ?')) { 

// Set the new activation code to 'activated', this is how we can check if the user has activated their account.
$newcode = 'activated';
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $newcode, $_GET['email'], $_GET['code']);
$stmt->execute();
echo'Su cuenta ha sido activada, ahora puede iniciar sesión!<br><a href="Logueo.html">Login</a>';
}
} else {
echo ' La cuenta ya está activada o no existe';
}
}
}

//// ** Verificación si usuario esta activado ** ////

// Now we check if the data from the login form was submitted, isset() will check if the data exists.
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
// Could not get the data that should have been sent.
die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}

// Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT id, password, activation_code FROM usuarios_sbr WHERE username = ?')) {

// Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();

// Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
$stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $activation_code);
$stmt->fetch();

// Account exists, now we verify the password.
// Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password) && $activation_code == 'activated') {

// Verification success! User has loggedin!
// Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.

session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
header('Location: home.php');
} else {
echo 'Contraseña incorrecta o cuenta no activada.';
}
} else {
echo 'Usuario incorrecto';
}
} else {
echo 'Contraseña incorrecta';
$stmt->close();
}
?>
```

El ingreso de los datos del formulario a la DB funciona y veo todos los campos. Para ello uso Dreamweaver CS6 y Xampp, versión del servidor 10.1.38 MariaDB,/ Apache/2.4.38,/ php versión 7.3.2,/ y phpmyadmin versión 4.9.5
No sé qué más explicar.

Comment: Has hecho debugs para ver hasta dónde llegan tus ifs?

Comment: Hola, no sé hacer eso, dije que no se programar. Gracias

Comment: Ok, una forma sencilla, es en cada `if` pon dentro un echo con palabras distintas, por ejemplo ` if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['code'])) { echo "entro al code"; ...` y así, en cada if, de esta forma, cuando entres y no imprima lo que pusiste, te puedes dar cuenta en que parte del código está el error, y una vez tengas cachada la parte, puedes mejorar la pregunta, ya que por ahora podrían ser mil cosas, tanto de la base de datos, como de la forma que entras, etc. ayudas a mejorar tu pregunta y poder ayudarte más fácilmente.

Comment: Perfecto, me pondré mañana a ello y actualizo, gracias.

Comment: Hola @Sr1871, estoy depurando como me aconsejaste, lo que no se es si lo hago bien o qué es lo que pasa, me explico, yo lo puse así ... if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['code'])) Depurando email y code { ... -es decir antes del corchete y si me muestra varios de los echo que puse, ahora bien si lo pongo según tu comentario - es decir tras el corchete if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['code'])) { Depurando email y code; refresco la página y no muestra ningun echo. A ver a que se debe.

Comment: podrías editar tu pregunta y poner como pones los echo?

Comment: Que alguien que sepa/pueda la ponga como solucionada.

Comment: La respuesta va abajo amigo en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné apenas hace unas horas, estaba escribiendo mal la url a mano, necesitaba poner .php?email=miemail&code numerodecodigo, yo ponía email sin & y el código, pero no me salía ningún echo no hemos podido activar su cuenta, ahora estoy liado con el carrito que no me muestra las imágenes de los productos llamadas con php, abriré consulta, gracias y un saludo. –